# utilising WebSockets or WebRTC to implement real-time communication in a React application for live updates or video conversation

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I want to include real-time communication capabilities in my React application, such live updates or video chat. For this, I'm thinking of leveraging WebSockets or WebRTC technologies. I'm not sure what procedures and best practises to follow to deploy these features successfully, though.

Specifically, I would like to know:

1)How can I integrate WebSockets or WebRTC into my React application to enable real-time communication?
2)What are the recommended libraries or frameworks to use for WebSockets or WebRTC in React?
3)How can I handle the signaling process, establishing connections, and managing data exchange between users in real-time?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Integrating WebSockets into a React App

To send and receive WebSockets message you need to use the
[WebSocket Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

You need to implement a Message Broker that your React Component can call and pass a callback function to. When a message is received, the Message Broker will call the callback function with the message.

2. Recommended libraries or Frameworks

The only standard protocols I'm aware of that sit on top of WebSockets are STOMP and WebRTC. There's a library called [react-stomp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stomp). See [Building WebRTC Chat App Article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/webrtc-client-chat-app-using-react-99bf8e803fd8) for a WebRTC demo.

The other option is to roll your own protocol. Use JSON messages between the client and server and implement a subscribe/publish messaging system. This is what I did. The WebSocket protocol I developed is called
[Brill Middleware](https://www.brill.software/brill_software/middleware).

3. Messaging between users in real-time.

Use a subscribe/publish messaging model. Each client subscribes to a topic. A topic might be for instance the name of a discussion forum. One of the clients publishes a message to the topic by sending a publish message to the server. The server maintains a list of all the subscribes and sends on the message to each of the clients that has a subscription. The Message Broker on the client forwards the message by calling the callback function of the React component which can then update the UI.